# SQL Error: ORA-00904: "GENDER": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE COM_MANAGEMENT (
    TITLE VARCHAR(20),
    name_a VARCHAR(20),
    POST VARCHAR(20),
    DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
    JOINING_DATE DATE,
    YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE NUMBER(4),
    PHONE NUMBER(15),
    E_MAIL VARCHAR(60),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
    GENDER VARCHAR(10)
);
```

If I want to insert data in this SQL the output given me SQL Error:

> ORA-00904: "GENDER": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" that's error

```
INSERT INTO COM_MANAGEMENT VALUES (TITLE('FRIENDS SHOP'),NAME_A('FOZLE'),POST('MD'), DATE_OF_BIRTH(1999-JAN-01), JOINING_DATE(1999-JAN-20),YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE(4),PHONE(017554122114),
E_MAIL('APPSLF@GMAIL.COM'),ADDRESS('FDSJDF'), GENDER(MALE));
```

Comment: Thats an Oracle error, but you have tagged MySQL and SQL Server - whats that about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be mixing and matching your SQL syntax here across different platforms.  Anyway, here's a quick fix

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE COM_MANAGEMENT (
  2      TITLE VARCHAR(20),
  3      name_a VARCHAR(20),
  4      POST VARCHAR(20),
  5      DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
  6      JOINING_DATE DATE,
  7      YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE NUMBER(4),
  8      PHONE NUMBER(15),
  9      E_MAIL VARCHAR(60),
 10      ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
 11      GENDER VARCHAR(10)
 12  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO COM_MANAGEMENT VALUES (TITLE('FRIENDS SHOP'),NAME_A('FOZLE'),POST('MD'), DATE_OF_BIRTH(1999-JAN-01),
  2  JOINING_DATE(1999-JAN-20),YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE(4),PHONE(017554122114),E_MAIL('APPSLF@GMAIL.COM'),ADDRESS('FDSJDF'), GENDER(MALE
));
JOINING_DATE(1999-JAN-20),YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE(4),PHONE(017554122114),E_MAIL('APPSLF@GMAIL.COM'),ADDRESS('FDSJDF'), GENDER(MALE))
                                                                                                                  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "GENDER": invalid identifier


SQL>
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO COM_MANAGEMENT
  2    (TITLE
  3   ,NAME_A
  4   ,POST
  5   ,DATE_OF_BIRTH
  6   ,JOINING_DATE
  7   ,YEAR_OF_EXPERIENCE
  8   ,PHONE
  9   ,E_MAIL
 10   ,ADDRESS
 11   ,GENDER
 12  )
 13  VALUES (
 14  'FRIENDS SHOP',
 15  'FOZLE',
 16  'MD',
 17  date '1999-01-01',
 18  date '1999-01-20',
 19  4,
 20  '017554122114',
 21  'APPSLF@GMAIL.COM',
 22  'FDSJDF',
 23  'MALE');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother